# Why am I getting a nulljavax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException?

Tags: email, exception, authentication, jakarta-mail

I am making a web app that sends emails automatically, so I am using javamail. I need to use the SMPT of my company, and no matter what I do I get a nulljavax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException. This is the first time I have used it and I'm really frustrated since I have tried a wide number of solutions and still I can't figure out what's wrong. I made a test using gmail and it worked, but so far nothing has helped. here's my code:

UPDATE: I have made changes to my code, and got rid of the authenticator as suggested.

```
     final String username = "dva.clamadrid@grupoautofin.com";
            final String password = "Leprechaun01";

            Properties props = new Properties();


            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");



            Session session = Session.getInstance(props);



            try {
                session.setDebug(true);
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("dva.clamadrid@grupoautofin.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("dva.clamadrid@grupoautofin.com"));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                        InternetAddress.parse(Copy));
                message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

                Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                transport.connect("SMTP.grupoautofin.com", 25, username, password);
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                transport.close();

                Log.i("Estás enviando: ",""+message.toString());

                System.out.println("Done");

            }catch(AuthenticationFailedException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR DE AUTENTIFICACION: ",""+e.getMessage()+e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 bandera = false;

            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                bandera=false;
                Log.e("ERROR ENVIANDO: ",""+e.getMessage()+e);

                e.printStackTrace();

                //throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

Also, my Error Log, now with Debug Messages:

```
10-13 15:56:13.504: I/System.out(802): DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
10-13 15:56:13.544: I/System.out(802): DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
10-13 15:56:13.544: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
10-13 15:56:13.544: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "SMTP.grupoautofin.com", port 25, isSSL false
10-13 15:56:13.835: I/System.out(802): 220 mtysmtp01.mexico.hosting.triara SMTP Server 01 is ready. Mon, 13 Oct 2014 14:56:13 -0500 
10-13 15:56:13.845: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "SMTP.grupoautofin.com", port: 25
10-13 15:56:13.855: I/System.out(802): EHLO localhost
10-13 15:56:13.905: I/System.out(802): 250-mtysmtp01.mexico.hosting.triara Hello [189.203.255.42]
10-13 15:56:13.905: I/System.out(802): 250-TURN
10-13 15:56:13.905: I/System.out(802): 250-SIZE 27262976
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-ETRN
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-PIPELINING
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-DSN
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-8bitmime
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-BINARYMIME
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-CHUNKING
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-VRFY
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN
10-13 15:56:13.915: I/System.out(802): 250-X-EXPS=LOGIN
10-13 15:56:13.925: I/System.out(802): 250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN
10-13 15:56:13.925: I/System.out(802): 250-AUTH=LOGIN
10-13 15:56:13.925: I/System.out(802): 250-X-LINK2STATE
10-13 15:56:13.925: I/System.out(802): 250-XEXCH50
10-13 15:56:13.925: I/System.out(802): 250 OK
10-13 15:56:13.935: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "TURN", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.935: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "27262976"
10-13 15:56:13.945: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.945: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.945: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.945: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.955: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8bitmime", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.955: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.955: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.965: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.965: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN"
10-13 15:56:13.965: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS=LOGIN", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.975: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN"
10-13 15:56:13.975: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=LOGIN", arg ""
10-13 15:56:13.985: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-LINK2STATE", arg ""
10-13 15:56:14.004: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XEXCH50", arg ""
10-13 15:56:14.004: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "OK", arg ""
10-13 15:56:14.015: I/System.out(802): DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
10-13 15:56:14.025: I/System.out(802): AUTH LOGIN
10-13 15:56:14.075: I/System.out(802): 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
10-13 15:56:14.085: I/System.out(802): ZHZhLmNsYW1hZHJpZEBncnVwb2F1dG9maW4uY29t
10-13 15:56:14.135: I/System.out(802): 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
10-13 15:56:14.135: I/System.out(802): TGVwcmVjaGF1bjAx
10-13 15:56:14.416: I/System.out(802): 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful.
10-13 15:56:14.424: E/ERROR DE AUTENTIFICACION:(802): nulljavax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
```

Still getting the same error, what else am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [you don't need the Authenticator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), get rid of it.

Second, you don't need the host, port, or auth properties if you're going to call the connect method explicitly so you can get rid of them too.

You've done something to verify that you're passing the correct username and password, right?

Turn on [session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and the debug output might provide more clues as to what's going wrong.  You might need to set the "mail.debug.auth" property to "true" to see the full authentication protocol exchange (which will include your password) to see the details of what's failing.  If you still can't figure it out, post the debug output (without the authentication exchange).

Comment: First, you're using a very old version of JavaMail.  As a consequence, the authentication protocol trace is included in the debug output, which anyone can decode to read your password. Please change your password immediately.  Second, weren't you setting the mail.smtp.starttls.enable property previously?  That seems to be gone now.  And you probably need that to switch to SSL/TLS before authenticating, so the server will be willing to accept your password.

Comment: Both of my issues were resolved, thanks for the input.